# Can a pointer point to a value and the pointer value point to the address?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference, dereference

Normal pointer usage as I have been reading in a book is the following:

```
int *pointer;
int number = 5;
pointer = &number;
```

Then *pointer has a value of 5.
But does this work the other way around? I mean:

```
int *pointer;
int number = 5;
*pointer = &number;
```

Here does pointer contain the value 5 and *pointer holds the address of number?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: You might want pointer of pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analogy from the department of far-fetched analogies:

You use pointers many times every day without even thinking about it.

A pointer is an *indirection* - it tells you *where* something is, or how it can be reached, but not *what* that thing is.
(In a typed language, you can know what *kind* of thing it is, but that's another matter.)

Consider, for example, telephone numbers.

These tell you how to reach the person that the phone number belongs to.
Over time, that person may change - perhaps somebody didn't pay their bills and the number was reassigned - but as long as the number is valid, you can use it to reach a person.

Using this analogy, we can define the following operations:

- `&person` gives you a person's phone number, and
- `*number` gives you the person that the number belongs to.

Some rules:

- There are only two types in this language - persons and phone numbers.
- Only persons can have phone numbers; `&number` is an error, as is `*person`.
- An unspecified phone number reaches the General Manager of Customer Services at Acme, Inc.

Now, your first example would translate to

```
PhoneNumber n;
Person Bob;
n = &Bob;
```

which makes sense; `n` now holds Bob's phone number.

Your second example would translate to

```
PhoneNumber n;
Person Bob;
*n = &Bob;
```

which would say "replace the General Manager of Acme Inc's Customer Services with Bob's phone number", which makes no sense at all.

And your final question,

> Here does pointer contain the value 5 and *pointer holds the address of number?

would translate to

> Is this phone number the same thing as Bob, and if you call it, will Bob's phone number answer?

which I am sure you can see is a rather strange question.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
int *pointer;
int number = 5;
*pointer = &number;
```

you never assign a valid address to `pointer`, so dereferencing that pointer (as is done by the expression `*pointer`) is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

Your second case will not compile, because the assignment `*pointer = &number` involves incompatible types (`int` on the left, a pointer to `int` on the right) which makes the assignment invalid.

If you somehow coerce the assignment into compiling, then `pointer` is not initialised.  Accessing its value, let alone dereferencing it (e.g. evaluating `*pointer` or assigning to it as in `*pointer = number` or `*pointer = 5`) gives undefined behaviour.    Anything can happen then .... depending on circumstances, a common result of undefined behaviour is an abnormal program termination.

Answer (score 2):

`*pointer = &number;` is not valid C.

`*pointer` is of type `int` and `&number` is of type `int*`. This isn't a valid form of assignment and will not compile on a standard C compiler.

You can store numbers inside pointer variables, but then you must use an explicit cast to force a type conversion. Some compilers allow it without an explicit cast, but note that doing so is a non-standard extension.

And of course, note that you haven't set `pointer` to point at an allocated memory address, so you can't store anything inside where it points.

If you do an explicit cast such as

```
pointer = &something;
*pointer = (int)&number;
```

then it is allowed in C, but if you try to de-reference that pointer, the behavior is implementation-defined. It could possibly also be undefined behavior in case of misalignment etc. See C11 6.3.2.3:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously
>   specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be
>   correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
>   type, and might be a trap representation.

Comment: TL;DR: Just stay away from writing nonsense code like this to begin with.

Comment: Alright got it thanks! I hadn't grasped the subject completely so it sounded right to my ears at the time.

Answer (score 1):

For you to write an assignment `x = y`, both `x` and `y` must be, or be implicitly convertible to, the same type (or `x` must have a user-defined assignment operator taking an argument matching the type of `y`, or ... OK, there are a few possibilities, but you get the idea).

Now, let's look at the statement

```
*pointer = &number;
```

Here, `*pointer` has type `int&` - you followed the pointer to get a (reference to) the integer stored at that location. Let's ignore, for now, the fact that your pointer was uninitialized and following it results in undefined behaviour.

The right hand side, `&number`, is taking a pointer to an integer variable, so the type is `int*`.

So, the expression doesn't make sense at all, just in terms of the type system: there is no way to assign `int*` to `int&`. It doesn't *mean* anything.

Let's relate it back to the English language of your question

> Here does pointer contain the value 5 and *pointer holds the address of number?

That translates directly to the type system, and hence *also* doesn't mean anything. Again, we can break it down

- > does pointer contain the value 5

  a pointer contains a *location*. The only time it would make sense to talk about a pointer having a literal value (other than `nullptr`) would be on a platform where there were well-known addresses - this is rare, and '5' is very unlikely to be a well-formed address anyway
- > *pointer holds the address

  well, there is a case where `*pointer` could hold an address - it's where `*pointer` is itself is a pointer, meaning the variable `pointer` is a pointer-to-pointer such as `int **`. That isn't the case here: we *know* the type of `*pointer` in your code, and it is `int&`, not `int*`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a pointer variable, initially it will have garbage value (let say 300 address location). Hence when you dereference pointer(*300), it would give another garbage value(value at 300 address location) or error (strictly speaking anything may happen depending on your computer).

In the third step, &number:- which is also another number and your are trying to assign a number to *pointer(may be another number) which not possible. (It is like this:- 5=6). Hence it will be an error.